# Detect Xcode Build/Run in Cocoa

Tags: xcode, cocoa

I was wondering if there was a way to detect a build or run in Xcode on a Cocoa app i.e. detect if the user of the app has built/run an xcode project?

Comment: as it happens (while Xcode is running) or after the fact (i.e. check X number of hours / days later)?

Comment: @MichaelDautermann as it happens.

Answer (score 0):

You can use @(**DATE**) for this.

```
NSString *versionText = [NSString stringWithFormat:"Version is %@",@(__DATE__)];
```